# Zapier Rest Hook Subscription - How to get target options?

Tags: rest, zapier

I am writing my first API integration with Zapier.  I have created a trigger using a REST hook, and the trigger is firing correctly, but I am not sure how to determine what trigger option the user selected in Zapier.  Specifically I allow them to choose a landing page, and unless I know WHICH landing page they want to activate the trigger I don't know how to handle it, but all I get back from Zapier on the subscription is this:

{
  "subscription_url": "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/standard/102653/94703dc5c31247c4acb8b82977fd08dc/",
  "target_url": "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/standard/102653/94703dc5c31247c4acb8b82977fd08dc/",
  "event": "landing_page_submitted"
}

I know I am probably missing something.  Should I expect to find the option selected in the trigger dropdown somewhere?  Or do I need to configure something on the Zapier side to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just need to pass the data in from `inputData`.

In your hook subscription, there's a place to pass data (such as `"event"` above). You can add something like `landing_page: bundle.inputData.landing_page`. There's a more complete example [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/43044f11eeb56efcab5322f55b9238782ca10372/example-apps/rest-hooks/triggers/recipe.js#L8):

```js
const subscribeHook = (z, bundle) => {

  // bundle.targetUrl has the Hook URL this app should call when a recipe is created.
  const data = {
    url: bundle.targetUrl,
    style: bundle.inputData.style
  };

  // You can build requests and our client will helpfully inject all the variables
  // you need to complete. You can also register middleware to control this.
  const options = {
    url: 'http://57b20fb546b57d1100a3c405.mockapi.io/api/hooks',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  // You may return a promise or a normal data structure from any perform method.
  return z.request(options)
    .then((response) => JSON.parse(response.content));
};
```